unexpected keyword argument 'metaclass'--problems when importing keras in conda
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout

here are my current code
the code runs find on jupyter lab yesterday but couldn't work today
at first I got this error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 6
      4 from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
      5 #plt.style.use("ggplot")
----> 6 import keras

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py:8
      1 """DO NOT EDIT.
      2 
      3 This file was autogenerated. Do not edit it by hand,
      4 since your modifications would be overwritten.
      5 """
----> 8 from keras import _tf_keras
      9 from keras import activations
     10 from keras import applications

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\keras\_tf_keras\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from keras._tf_keras import keras

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\keras\_tf_keras\keras\__init__.py:8
      1 """DO NOT EDIT.
      2 
      3 This file was autogenerated. Do not edit it by hand,
      4 since your modifications would be overwritten.
      5 """
----> 8 from keras import activations
      9 from keras import applications
     10 from keras import callbacks

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\keras\activations\__init__.py:8
      1 """DO NOT EDIT.
      2 
      3 This file was autogenerated. Do not edit it by hand,
      4 since your modifications would be overwritten.
      5 """
----> 8 from keras.src.activations import deserialize
      9 from keras.src.activations import get
     10 from keras.src.activations import serialize

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\keras\src\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from keras.src import activations
      2 from keras.src import applications
      3 from keras.src import backend

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\keras\src\activations\__init__.py:3
      1 import types
----> 3 from keras.src.activations.activations import elu
      4 from keras.src.activations.activations import exponential
      5 from keras.src.activations.activations import gelu

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\keras\src\activations\activations.py:1
----> 1 from keras.src import backend
      2 from keras.src import ops
      3 from keras.src.api_export import keras_export

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\__init__.py:10
      7     import torch
      9 from keras.src.backend.common.dtypes import result_type
---> 10 from keras.src.backend.common.keras_tensor import KerasTensor
     11 from keras.src.backend.common.keras_tensor import any_symbolic_tensors
     12 from keras.src.backend.common.keras_tensor import is_keras_tensor

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\common\keras_tensor.py:2
      1 from keras.src.api_export import keras_export
----> 2 from keras.src.utils import tree
      3 from keras.src.utils.naming import auto_name
      6 @keras_export("keras.KerasTensor")
      7 class KerasTensor:

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\tree.py:5
      2 import collections.abc
      3 import types
----> 5 import optree
      7 from keras.src.api_export import keras_export
      8 from keras.src.backend.config import backend

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\optree\__init__.py:17
      1 # Copyright 2022-2024 MetaOPT Team. All Rights Reserved.
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     13 # limitations under the License.
     14 # ==============================================================================
     15 """OpTree: Optimized PyTree Utilities."""
---> 17 from optree import integration, typing
     18 from optree.ops import (
     19     MAX_RECURSION_DEPTH,
     20     NONE_IS_LEAF,
   (...)
     72     treespec_tuple,
     73 )
     74 from optree.registry import (
     75     AttributeKeyPathEntry,
     76     GetitemKeyPathEntry,
   (...)
     81     unregister_pytree_node,
     82 )

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\optree\typing.py:44
     41 from typing_extensions import TypeAlias  # Python 3.10+
     42 from typing_extensions import Final, Protocol, runtime_checkable  # Python 3.8+
---> 44 from optree import _C
     45 from optree._C import PyTreeKind, PyTreeSpec
     48 __all__ = [
     49     'PyTreeSpec',
     50     'PyTreeDef',
   (...)
     80     'Deque',
     81 ]

ImportError: cannot import name '_C' from partially initialized module 'optree' (most likely due to a circular import) (D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\optree\__init__.py)

I think it might be a package problem so I install tensorflow and keras on my conda environment
then I got this error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 6
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
----> 6 from keras.models import Sequential
      7 from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py:20
     18 from keras import export
     19 from keras import initializers
---> 20 from keras import layers
     21 from keras import legacy
     22 from keras import losses

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\keras\distribute\__init__.py:18
      1 # Copyright 2019 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     13 # limitations under the License.
     14 # ==============================================================================
     15 """Keras' Distribution Strategy library."""
---> 18 from keras.distribute import sidecar_evaluator

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\keras\distribute\sidecar_evaluator.py:17
      1 # Copyright 2020 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     13 # limitations under the License.
     14 # ==============================================================================
     15 """Python module for evaluation loop."""
---> 17 import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
     19 # isort: off
     20 from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py:45
     42 from tensorflow.python import tf2 as _tf2
     43 _tf2.enable()
---> 45 from tensorflow._api.v2 import __internal__
     46 from tensorflow._api.v2 import __operators__
     47 from tensorflow._api.v2 import audio

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\__init__.py:13
     11 from . import distribute
     12 from . import eager_context
---> 13 from . import feature_column
     14 from . import function
     15 from . import graph_util

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\feature_column\__init__.py:8
      3 """Public API for tf.__internal__.feature_column namespace.
      4 """
      6 import sys as _sys
----> 8 from tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column_v2 import DenseColumn
      9 from tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column_v2 import FeatureColumn
     10 from tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column_v2 import FeatureTransformationCache

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column_v2.py:137
    135 from tensorflow.python.data.ops import readers
    136 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
--> 137 from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column as fc_old
    138 from tensorflow.python.feature_column import utils as fc_utils
    139 from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py:143
    141 from tensorflow.python.framework import sparse_tensor as sparse_tensor_lib
    142 from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_shape
--> 143 from tensorflow.python.layers import base
    144 from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
    145 from tensorflow.python.ops import check_ops

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py:16
      1 # Copyright 2015 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     13 # limitations under the License.
     14 # =============================================================================
     15 """Contains the base Layer class, from which all layers inherit."""
---> 16 from tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers import base
     18 InputSpec = base.InputSpec
     20 keras_style_scope = base.keras_style_scope

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py:25
     22 from tensorflow.python.keras import distribute
     24 # See b/110718070#comment18 for more details about this import.
---> 25 from tensorflow.python.keras import models
     27 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer import Input
     28 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential import Sequential

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models.py:20
     18 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
     19 from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
---> 20 from tensorflow.python.keras import metrics as metrics_module
     21 from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizer_v1
     22 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import functional

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py:34
     32 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
     33 from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_shape
---> 34 from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
     35 from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
     36 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import base_layer

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\activations.py:18
     15 """Built-in activation functions."""
     17 from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
---> 18 from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import advanced_activations
     19 from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
     20 from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils import serialize_keras_object

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\__init__.py:22
     17 from tensorflow.python import tf2
     19 # Generic layers.
     20 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
     21 # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
---> 22 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer import Input
     23 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer import InputLayer
     24 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_spec import InputSpec

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_layer.py:24
     22 from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
     23 from tensorflow.python.keras.distribute import distributed_training_utils
---> 24 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import base_layer
     25 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import keras_tensor
     26 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import node as node_module

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:53
     51 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import node as node_module
     52 from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision import autocast_variable
---> 53 from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision import loss_scale_optimizer
     54 from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision import policy
     55 from tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model import layer_serialization

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\mixed_precision\loss_scale_optimizer.py:29
     27 from tensorflow.python.framework import smart_cond
     28 from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
---> 29 from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers
     30 from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision import loss_scale as keras_loss_scale_module
     31 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2 import optimizer_v2

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizers.py:24
     22 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v1 import Optimizer
     23 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v1 import TFOptimizer
---> 24 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2 import adadelta as adadelta_v2
     25 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2 import adagrad as adagrad_v2
     26 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2 import adam as adam_v2

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\adadelta.py:22
     20 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
     21 from tensorflow.python.keras import backend_config
---> 22 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2 import optimizer_v2
     23 from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
     24 from tensorflow.python.training import gen_training_ops

File D:\Anaconda\envs\test05\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:111
    107   else:
    108     return NullContextmanager()
--> 111 @keras_export("keras.optimizers.Optimizer", metaclass=abc.ABCMeta)
    112 class OptimizerV2(trackable.Trackable):
    113   """Base class for Keras optimizers.
    114 
    115   You should not use this class directly, but instead instantiate one of its
   (...)
    298       (serialization of the optimizer, include all hyper parameters)
    299   """
    301   # Subclasses should set this to True unless they override `apply_gradients`
    302   # with a version that does not have the `experimental_aggregate_gradients`
    303   # argument.  Older versions of Keras did not have this argument so custom
   (...)
    306   # `experimental_aggregate_gradients` if this attribute is True.
    307   # Note: This attribute will likely be removed in an upcoming release.

TypeError: api_export.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'metaclass'

I currently have not idea what was happening. The code works find yesterday

Hi @pinru chen there's a compatibility issue between TensorFlow, Keras, and some other libraries. The errors you're encountering suggest that there might be conflicts or inconsistencies between different versions of these libraries.Ensure that all your libraries, including TensorFlow and Keras, are up-to-date.Make sure that there are no conflicting versions of TensorFlow or Keras installed.
